# ran php_e and output inside html comment automaticly <-- --> (WordPress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is my first question and i'm not sure if i open it as well. I'm a noob programmer :) Please bear with me.

**This is a problem:**
I'm not getting an error when i put wrong/empty username and password on my login page. Seems that php_e does not work.

But i see it **HTML COMMENTED** in chrome "view source" 
Screenshot available: http://s28.postimg.org/v77y6gfe5/111.jpg

**Here is part of code:**

```
if($_POST){
    if ( is_wp_error($user_verify) ) {
$UserError = "<?php _e( 'Invalid username or password. Please try again!', 'agrg' ); ?>";

    } else {

        global $alo_in; 
        $profile = $alo_in['profile'];
        wp_redirect( $profile ); exit;

    }
}
```

**Question:**

Why it's in HTML comment? And how cat i output regular error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting `<?php ?>` tag inside the php string which is wrong!

Remove quotes and PHP tags also in place of `_e()` use `__()` which actually return the string.

```
$UserError = __( 'Invalid username or password. Please try again!', 'agrg' );
```

So you can print `$UserError` variable which contain your custom error message.